# Search a range for a value, return the value of the first cell in the matched column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a table, such as:

```
     A          B         C
1    Animals    Colors    States
2    Cat        Red       CT
3    Dog        Orange    CA
4    Mouse      Yellow    CO
```

I want to search for `Yellow`, and get `Colors` as a result.

I feel like one of the `LOOKUP` options should work here, but I'm not having luck. Is there a way to do this with a formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D1: `Yellow`

E1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(,1,IF(D1=A2:C4,A1:C1,)))
```

- IF to get headers
- TEXTJOIN to remove blanks

Comment: Wow, that's so simple. Do you happen to know of documentation supporting this method? I'm searching but likely not using the proper terms.

Comment: I've seen the basic syntax, but never with ranges and the result pointing to a specific row like that before. I'll take a look as well.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the info!